# Total memory vs memory per CPU vs memory per process

Tags: memory, cpu, process

I have troubles understanding memory (RAM) specifications of CPUs. Just as an example, the [Xeon Gold 6144](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124943/intel-xeon-gold-6144-processor-24-75m-cache-3-50-ghz.html) specs give a maximal memory size of 768GB. If I have a mainboard with two CPU sockets and 24 memory banks which I fill up with 64GB modules each so that I have 1.5TB of memory in total, then how much memory can a single process consume/access? 768GB or the full 1.5TB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Max Memory Size" of 768GB means what it says: Each CPU can only address up to 768GB
of RAM.

If you put more than 768GB in the computer, and have two CPUs,
it is up to the motherboard to decide what each CPU will see.

The CPU has the respectable number of 6 Memory Channels, so depending on the
number of RAM sticks and their channels you may have a nice bandwidth,
but again, depending on the motherboard.

Comment: Also, read up on NUMA, Non-Uniform Memory Access, which couples each CPU to their own local memory via a fast local memory controller, but allows access to memory from another CPU via a (slower) interconnect. See here: https://frankdenneman.nl/2016/07/07/numa-deep-dive-part-1-uma-numa/

Answer (score 0):

If the mainboard's hard- and firmware impose no limits outside of what you specified, you will indeed be able to address 1.5TB on the OS level.

What's available to a single process is a completly other question, that has much less to do with the hardware than with your operating system. If I assume a modern Linux x64 kernel, you can use nearly all of it for a single process.